# Find inputs that are not checkbox type, not input type, and are textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have the following code:

```
jQuery(form).find("input[type!='checkbox'], textarea").each(function(i){
```

Which gives me the inputs which type is not checkbox, and also the textarea elements.

How can I make it more restrictive so that it also avoids the input with type submit?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you going the long way? Are you just experimenting? Normally you would just do jQuery(form).find('textarea').each...or $('form textarea') which gets all textareas for the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple attribute selectors just by repeating the square bracket `[]` notation such as

```
input[type!='checkbox'][type!='submit']
```

So you can use:

```
jQuery(form).find("input[type!='checkbox'][type!='submit'], textarea").each(function(i){
```

- [jQuery docs for Multiple Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: Cool! I was doing type!='checkbox' && type!='submit']